# Is there a way to preserve image proportions when using an <a-image> tag?

Tags: aframe

Is there a way to preserve image proportions when using an  tag?

The docs mention hard coding the dimensions but that's problematic when requesting arbitrary images

https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/primitives/a-image.html

Answer (score 0):

as far as i see, the `a-image` is just a `a-plane` with an image source in a material.

It means the image will be streched over the plane, you can only mess with the

- `<a-image>` height and width, which are the **a-plane**'s height and width in meters,
- `<img>` height and width, which specify the image dimensions in px, but the image still will be streched over the plane.

You could try to do it automatically, within a component, setting the `a-plane`width and height depending on the input `<img>` width and height, having a px-meters ratio:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('imageSetter',{
  schema:{
     img:{type:'selector'}
  },
  init:function(){
      let lowResRatio = 0.01;
      this.el.setAttribute('height',this.data.img.height*lowResRatio);
      this.el.setAttribute('width',this.data.img.width*lowResRatio);
  }
});
```

Check it out in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/5d9j9nqm/2/.

Otherwise, You need to prepare the images earlier on.
**UPDATE**

You can modify the component so it gets the image dimensions, gets a height/width ratio, and sets the width and height accordingly:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo',{
  schema:{
    img:{type:'selector',default:''},
    height:{}
  },
  init:function(){
    let data = this.data;
    let ratio = 1/100;
    this.el.setAttribute('width',data.img.width*ratio);
    this.el.setAttribute('height',data.height);
    this.el.addEventListener('materialtextureloaded', (e)=>{
    var w = e.detail.texture.image.videoWidth ||   e.detail.texture.image.width;
    var h = e.detail.texture.image.videoHeight || e.detail.texture.image.height;
    let ratio = w/h;
    this.el.setAttribute('width',data.height*ratio);
    });
  }
})
```

live fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5d9j9nqm/4/

Now it's fixing itself to a given height.

Comment: I think the [fit-texture](https://github.com/nylki/aframe-fit-texture-component) component tries to do this.

Comment: @bryik oh, didn't see it earlier, I cant get it working: https://jsfiddle.net/5d9j9nqm/3/ ( last image ), don't know why, though it seems to get the ratio, and set the width/height accordingly,

Comment: fit texture looks great, but sadly, it doesnt work for me either

Comment: If i understand your solution correctly, it still requires prior knowledge of the images dimensions. I am looking for a solution that will gather that knowledge from whatever image happens to be requested.